# Automatic Shutdown?

Tags: 14.04, shutdown

My laptop is shutting down automatically after 4 hours continuous usage. Is there is any default settings in Ubuntu or any installation problem. My system having 3GB RAM and I installed Ubuntu on 50GB drive with swap 10GB.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an overheating problem - does it feel hot? You can install lm-sensors / gkrellm for a real-time temp. display to check - or you could just try blowing out the fan vents or a laptop cooler, if you have one - assuming it's not a new laptop (in which cae, consider warranty..). 4 hours seems a long time for a software fault, especially if it's repeatable. Installing powertop is also a good move for laptops, you can turn down a lot of power use.